# Type Casting in Java for Boxed Class?

Tags: java, class, casting

With Possible Un-boxing in Java Why can't I Downcast With Integer Class.

```
double a=20.3;
int b=(Integer)a;
```

It gives me error incompatible Type Conversion. My question is why Integer class is not able to Downcast it like

```
int b=(int)a;
```

Does Casting works with class for primitive type in Java?

Answer (score 0):

double can't autobox into Integer. However, int can autobox into Integer. See [docs here.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html)

```
    double a=20.3;
    Integer b = (int) a;
    int c = b; // c = 20;
```